# Package visible in Synaptic but not in aptitude?

Tags: ubuntu-9.10, aptitude, synaptic-pkg-mgr

I can see libfreeimage3-dev in synaptic and have installed it from there, but what is it that I can't see it from the command line? I tried sudo aptitude update...

```
mike@sleepycat:~$ sudo aptitude search '~n.*freeimage3.*'
i   libfreeimage3                   - Support library for graphics image formats
p   libfreeimage3-dbg               - Support library for graphics image formats
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The package you want is actually `libfreeimage-dev`. Your pattern doesn't match that, because it has the `3` in it.

Also, your pattern is overly complicated, and searching doesn't need `sudo`. Instead:

```
aptitude search freeimage
```

which returns:

```
p   libfreeimage-dev         - Support library for graphics image formats
p   libfreeimage3            - Support library for graphics image formats
p   libfreeimage3-dbg        - Support library for graphics image formats
```